# Python - adding correct protocol when user inputs a domain name

Tags: python, selenium

I want my program to take a command line argument like "google.com" and get source code back using Selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(sys.args[0])
```

However, I get issues because no protocol is defined in the user input. My fix to check for protocol has been this:

```
if not "http://" in url and not "https://" in url:
    urlWithProtocol = "https://" + url
else:
    urlWithProtocol = url
```

What I can't figure out is how to determine if the added protocol should be https:// or http://

Thoughts?

Comment: Why should it matter? If you leave it as http and the site requires https, it will redirect the client to the https page. Leave it as http and let Selenium handle the rest.

Comment: Oh....well I feel foolish. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Aldehir please post your comment as an answer so CatLord can mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you leave it as http and the site requires https, it will redirect the client to the https page. Leave it as http and let Selenium handle the rest.