# How to get redirected final url with Got in Node.js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to visit a hundred thousand or more urls and check if they redirect to a different final url.

I'm using https://www.scrapeulous.com to do this. But I'll need to write a simple custom function to make it work. Scrapeulous uses the got library. Which has [documentation that on the followRedirects option that notes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#followredirect):

> followRedirect
>
> Type: boolean Default: true
>
> Defines if redirect responses should be followed automatically.
>
> Note that if a 303 is sent by the server in response to any request
> type (POST, DELETE, etc.), Got will automatically request the resource
> pointed to in the location header via GET. This is in accordance with
> the spec.

and [also notes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#url-1) for Response.url:

> url
>
> Type: string
>
> The request URL or the final URL after redirects.

I've tried the following code to no avail:

```
class Get extends HttpWorker {
  async crawl(url) {
    let result = await this.Got(encodeURI(url),
    {followRedirect: true});
    return result.url;
  }
}
```

I've never written any javascript or node.js before so be gentle. Let's use debianit.com which redirects to experait.com as my example. Side note: I'd also like to be able to feed the code domains instead of urls to determine if a site defaults to http:// or https://. But one solution at a time is enough for me :).

I also tried returning the entire result object and looking through it but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Have more clarity on this.

First, there are three types of redirects (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310219/anyway-to-scrape-a-link-that-redirects)):

1. HTTP - as information in response headers (with code 301, 302, 3xx)
2. HTML - as tag  in HTML (wikipedia: Meta refresh)
3. JavaScript - as code like window.location = new_url

With respect to the example domain, debianit.com. It redirects to experait.com via javascript. Specifically this script:

```
  <script>
   var url= "https://www.experaIT.com"; 
    window.location = url;
  </script>
```

The Got documentation states that it will follow redirects:

> if a 303 is sent by the server in response to any request type

Put differently, it doesn't appear got will follow meta or javascript redirects. Though you could parse the resulting html and extract the url from the javascript window.location or from the meta tag.

Obviously, using the BrowserWorker class instead of the HttpWorker class will also work. Here's the scrapeulous code that would work for that.

```
class Render extends BrowserWorker {
  async crawl(url) {
    await this.page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2', // two open connections is okay
    });

    return await this.page.url();
  }
}
```

As for my side note about how to figure out the correct protocol to append to a domain name. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090433/puppeteer-doesnt-open-a-url-without-protocol) chromium doesn't have the same omnibox functionality as chrome does, however, [per this answer about the selenium python browser,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339718/python-adding-correct-protocol-when-user-inputs-a-domain-name) you can work around this by appending http:// and letting chromium sort out if the page redirects to https:// or not.